# Вывод списка адресов на яндекс картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть просто список адресов домов, например "Украина Донецк Кирова 4" и т.д Нужно разместить их на карте со своими метками и описанием. Т.е. что то вроде этого:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Размещение карты на странице.</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Размещение карты на странице</h2>

    <script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU"
            type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Как только будет загружен API и готов DOM, выполняем инициализацию
        ymaps.ready(init);

        function init () {
            var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                    center: [55.76, 37.64],
                    zoom: 10
                }),

                // Создаем метку и задаем изображение для ее иконки
                myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.76, 37.64], {
                    balloonContent: 'Bingo!'
                }, {
                    iconImageHref: 'http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/examples/images/myIcon.gif', // картинка иконки
                    iconImageSize: [30, 42], // размеры картинки
                    iconImageOffset: [-3, -42] // смещение картинки
                });

                myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark([55.76, 37.60], {
                    balloonContent: 'Bingo! 2'
                }, {
                    iconImageHref: 'http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/examples/images/myIcon.gif', // картинка иконки
                    iconImageSize: [30, 42], // размеры картинки
                    iconImageOffset: [-3, -42] // смещение картинки
                });

            // Добавление метки на карту
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark2);
        }
    </script>

<div id="map" style="width:600px; height:300px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

только не по координатам, т.к. у меня их нет, определять их и выводить думаю не лучший вариант, можно их как то поиском выводить ?

Answer (score 2):

В АПИ Яндекс карт есть геокодер
см. http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/dg/concepts/geocoding.xml
а здесь примеры "Определение координат по адресу и адреса по координатам"

http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/examples/

И если погуглить по теме "Геокодирование в Яндекс картах" можно много примеров найти.

Comment: Мне не понятно как их использовать, как вывести сразу много адресов на карте и как присвоить в данном случае каждой метке свою иконку со своим описанием ?

Comment: Когда добавляется адрес — обращаетесь к геокодеру, получаете его координаты. После этого координаты записываете себе и используете на карте как требуется.

Не мучать же геокодер на каждый показ карты.

Comment: конечно не надо мучать геокодер.
В пользовательском соглашении четко прописано что можно кешировать данные геокодера для уменьшения нагрузки. Да и количество обращений к геокодеру в сутки ограничено. В клубе разработчиков АПИ Яндекс карт есть примеры кода. Если в кеше нет координат объекта определяем их с помощью геокодера и сохраняем в кеше.